# py2neo.database.status.CypherSyntaxError: Invalid input 'O': expected 't/T'

Tags: neo4j

Here is a query that I am trying to run in Neo4j version 3.1.1
What is wrong with this query?

```
CREATE (ee:officers { name: KIM SOO IN, icij_id: E72326DEA50F1A9C2876E112AAEB42BC, 
 valid_until: The Panama Papers data is current through 2015,
 country_codes: KOR, countries: South Korea, sourceID: Panama Papers, 
 note: , node_id: 12000001 })
```

Please help me rectify the query.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes

```
CREATE (ee:officers { name: "KIM SOO IN", icij_id: "E72326DEA50F1A9C2876E112AAEB42BC", 
valid_until: "The Panama Papers data is current through 2015",
country_codes: "KOR", countries: "South Korea", sourceID: "Panama Papers", 
note:"" , node_id: 12000001 })
```